# EF5 code first with MVC 4 UserProfile in place

Tags: entity-framework

This must be very simple, but I am feeling stupid today, so here goes:

I create a new MVC 4 Internet application using templates supplied by VS2012. The app comes with AccountModels which define, among other things, UserProfile. There is also UserContext that has

```
public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
```

So far so good. Now I am starting my own model, adding a Project class where I want to reference UserProfile. I have my own DataContext that defines

```
public DbSet<Project>   Projects { get; set; }
```

I haven't run a single migration yet, so my Project table is not there. But UserProfile is already part of my database along with webpages_* tables used by SimpleMembership. How can I add a navigation property in Project that points to UserProfile?

Comment: It is bad practice to have foreign key (in the database) to the membership tables, but you can add an association in your EF model. Is your question about how to do that or about how to do the migration?

Comment: I don't see how it is a bad practice. Yes, I would like to know how to add this association to my model and run a migration with it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's bad practice to add a relationship to the UsersProfile table.  You will need to create your POCO classes, enable migrations, configure your account model to form the relationship that you want with your Projects class, then update the database to reflect the model changes.  There is a walkthrough at http://evonet.com.au/code-first-development-with-the-entity-framework/